# Spring Boot @ApplicationProperties not using values from test profile

Tags: spring-boot, configuration

I have created a class annotated with `@ApplicationProperties`

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myapp.security")
class SecurityProperties {
    lateinit var signingKey: String
}
```

And a test to see if the values are retrieved from the config file

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@SpringBootTest
@Profile("security-properties-test")
class SecurityPropertiesTest {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var securityProperties: SecurityProperties

    @Test
    fun `security properties are set`(){
        securityProperties.signingKey shouldBe "theSigningKey"
    }
}
```

When I create some values in the default application.yml, the value is picked up and everything works

```
spring:
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
myapp:
  security:
    signing-key: theSigningKey
```

But when I try to override the value in a profile, the value from the default profile is still used

```
spring:
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
myapp:
  security:
    signing-key: theSigningKey

---
spring:
  profiles: security-properties-test
myapp:
  security:
    signing-key: anothertheSigningKey
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You have used the wrong annotation on your test class. It should be annotated with `@ActiveProfiles` rather than `@Profile`.